# Can not create table in MySQL workbench 5.2.40

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've just created anew schema & want to create a new table. When ever I right click on 2myschema' that I created, and select 'new table',

[image]

I give a name for the table to be created, but I get the following error:

[image]

I searched about the error, and I found that the cause if I typed a reserved word such as 'order' but there is no way that table2 is reserved word, and I tried many different names and always get the same message. The column Name is not activated, so I can't enter column names.

Comment: You need to define some columns.  A table cannot exist without any columns (what would be the point?).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out that the columns area was not disabled, but it needed scroll down from the thin rectangle as shown below. I was trying to type column name in the square below this rectangle and beased on that I described it as disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to scroll down but make your window taller. You have an extremely small WB window height. On the right hand side of the table editor there's also a double arrow pointing down. Click this to collapse the upper part (with the collation and comments edits) and you will get more room for the lower part.

Note: there's also a splitter between the table editor and the output tab, so you can increase the table editor space by sacrifying some output space.

Answer (score 1):

You have no columns in your table, so what should your table represent?

Comment: The columns are is disabled. I can't enter anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a table without columns. That is not possible

Comment: The columns are is disabled. I can't enter anything

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor.html)